# Wordpress Plugin : Multiple values against same setting

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am writing a plugin for category discounts. In Plugin Setting page, I have a `Category` and `Discount_percentage` fields. I am rending these as followings

```
function cat_slug_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'slug-configuration' );
    ?>
    <input type='text' size="50" name='slug-configuration[cat_slug]' value='<?php echo $options['cat_slug']; ?>'>
    <?php

}
```

and defining the option as

```
add_settings_field(
            'cat_slug', //id
            'category Slug',  //title
            'cat_slug_render', // callable 
            'slug-configuration', // page
            'configuration' //  section 
        );
```

everything else is fine. I can save the settings, can retrieve it, can update it and all.
However, I can save `just ONE` value. My aim is to `save multiple values using the same fields`.

But I am confused here how can I do it. My ultimate goal is as follows

```
input cat slug
Input discount
Press save
this will insert a New record each time this process is done
```

any guidance or help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to `[cat_slug]` as an array during save by using `[]` in the `name` attribute:

```
function cat_slug_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'slug-configuration', array() );
    ?>
    <input type='text' size="50" name='slug-configuration[cat_slug][]' value='<?php echo esc_html( $options['cat_slug'][0] ?? '' ); ?>'>
    <?php
}
```

However, you'll have to decide which value should be pre-loaded into the field if you are going to save multiple values. The first? The last? I've added `[0]` to the value, which should show the first, but if you want the most recent you could do something like:

```
function cat_slug_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'slug-configuration', array() );
    $last_key = array_key_last( $options );
    ?>
    <input type='text' size="50" name='slug-configuration[cat_slug][]' value='<?php echo esc_html( $options['cat_slug'][$last_key] ?? '' ); ?>'>
    <?php
}
```

Obviously make sure to update your sanitizer function if you try this, and note that `value` should be secured using `esc_html()` as well as your preferred method of `isset` (I've used `??` from PHP 7 or higher) if you want to prevent errors when nothing has been saved.

To display or use the values you've saved, you can use a foreach loop on the `[cat_slug]` array key:

```
$options = get_option( 'slug-configuration', array() )[cat_slug] ?? array();

foreach( $options as $option ) {

    // Do stuff.

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, that makes perfect sense, and point me if I am wrong, when I want to show the saved values, I will loop over with foreach loop on $options array and will access the values like $option['cat_slug']. Please point me if I am wrong, going to implement in a while, yet if I can have a better approach, it will be good to learn. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer to include how to retrieve the values.

Comment: I can't upvote you twice for the beauty of code and usage of '??' operator, Awesome, and thank you so much.